# Generate Pandas DF OHLC data with Numpy

Tags: numpy, pandas

I would like to generate the following test data in my dataframe in a way similar to this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.linspace(1800, 100, 400), index=pd.date_range(end='2015-07-02', periods=400), columns=['close'])
df

    close
2014-05-29  1800.000000
2014-05-30  1795.739348
2014-05-31  1791.478697
2014-06-01  1787.218045
```

But using the following criteria:

- intervals of 1 minute
- increments of .25
- prices moving up and down around 1800.00
- maximum 2100.00, minimum 1700.00
- parse_dates= "Timestamp"
- Volume column rows have a range of min = 50 - max = 300
- Day start 09:30 Day End 16:29:59

Please see desired output:

```
                       Open High    Low   Last      Volume
Timestamp                   
2014-03-04 09:30:00 1783.50 1784.50 1783.50 1784.50 171
2014-03-04 09:31:00 1784.75 1785.75 1784.50 1785.25 28
2014-03-04 09:32:00 1785.00 1786.50 1785.00 1786.50 81
2014-03-04 09:33:00 1786.00
```

I have limited python experience and find the example for Numpy etc hard to follow as they look to be focused on academia.  Is it possible to assist with this?

Comment: If the ohlc element is too difficult I would be more than happy if someone could generate even a single column as specified. Volume is also not essential.  Thanks